# Code below affecting execution of earlier code

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I am working on a project for a class and I was running it a few times and it was working fine. All of a sudden, after only changing a text file it was reading from and nothing else, it stopped working. I ran it and it simply ran on forever. I added a printf to the top to start seeing what was holding me. When I compiled and ran that the printf didn't activate, nothing happened. When commented out the body of my code, compiled it, and ran it, the printf worked fine. I have never seen anything like this. How can that happen? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    FILE *list = fopen("pwlist1.txt","r");
    if (list == NULL) {
        printf("File fail\n");
        exit(1);
   }
   const size_t line_size = 30;
   char* line = malloc(line_size);
   char buffer[256];
   strcpy(buffer,"FAILURE: ");
   while (fgets(line, line_size, list) != NULL && strstr(buffer, "FAILURE:") != NULL) {
       portno = 48579;
       sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
       if (sockfd < 0) 
           error("ERROR opening socket");

       server = gethostbyname("elnux1.cs.umass.edu");
       if (server == NULL) {
           fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
           exit(0);
       }
       bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
       serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
       bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
       serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
       if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
           error("ERROR connecting");
       n = write(sockfd,"bloop",strlen("bloop"));
       if (n < 0) 
           error("ERROR writing to socket");
       bzero(buffer,256);
       n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
       if (n < 0) 
           error("ERROR reading from socket");
       n = write(sockfd,"667057",strlen("667057"));
       if (n < 0) 
           error("ERROR writing to socket");
       bzero(buffer,256);
       n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
       if (n < 0) 
           error("ERROR reading from socket");
       n = write(sockfd,line,strlen(line));
       if (n < 0) 
           error("ERROR writing to socket");
       bzero(buffer,256);
       n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
       if (n < 0) 
           error("ERROR reading from socket");
    }
    if (strstr(buffer, "FAILURE:") == NULL) printf("You did it! The word is: %s\n",line);
    else printf("Failure.\n");
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Contents of pwlist1.txt:

```
test
hi
```

Comment: What is incorrect about it?

Comment: As a rule, if something is failing randomly, check for memory errors. Compile with `-Werror -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -fsanitize=address` and run it.

Comment: Thanks but the code still loops on forever after the second ping.

Comment: It looks like your program is depending on your stack buffers having `'\0'`s in the right place for you. The introduction of the `printf()` may have changed things sufficiently that your uninitialized buffers have different things in them. Try initializing them.

Comment: When you say "after the second ping", do you mean the one in the `while()` loop?

Comment: Are you working with a VCS (version control system)?  If so, did you save a copy of your working code?  So can you revert to the working code, after making a copy of your broken code, so you can make the changes incrementally and test them?  If you aren't working with a VCS, now you know why you should be.  It allows you to save working versions, giving you the confidence to be able to go back and find what you've changed, etc.

Comment: I removed the printf's in the while loop body. It still does nothing when run.

Comment: I am not working with a VCS but the error didn't occur after changing the program. I changed a text file it was getting input from.

Comment: What was different about the other file?

Comment: It is a list of words. I just changed the words in the list like I have done previously. I am trying to solve a riddle and send the answer to the server as part of the class. After spending hours changing items on that text list it the program that had been working fine just stopped running.

Comment: Are any of the words longer than 29 characters?

Comment: Nope, the are all under 10.

Comment: You are not stating a specific problem, so as it stands, this question is not very helpful to future programmers. There are numerous reasons for the behavior you describe. Perhaps, one of your `write()`s is not sending enough data for the server, and so your `read()` is blocked waiting for data from the server, who is also waiting for more data from you. Or, perhaps, you are trying to `read()` more bytes than the server will actually send. There is too little information to go on from your program alone. The server behavior is also required.

Comment: I am sorry my question isn't better. If I could understand what was happening specifically I would look it up. I am honestly at a loss on where to even start with this.

Comment: Compile your program with with debugging symbols and run it under a debugger. When it seems like it is in a stuck state, break out of the program and see what line of code it is stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for the problem you describe (of a `printf` not outputting when you comment in the rest of your code) is that `stdout` is not being flushed. You can fix this by adding an explicit flush after your `printf`.

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Since it is not clear from your question exactly which `printf` you are having a problem with, I would also flush `stderr` for good measure.

```
fflush(stderr);
```